# Website published but still says coming soon on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web, elementor, vs-web-site-project

My website has been published on wordpress but everytime I search for it like " site:Swirl-x.com" it says Swirl-x.com - Coming soon. The website has been launched and is live state why do I still get the coming soon how can i fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the same google search console account, you can do this yourself.

1. Log in to google search console
2. Select the property (property for Swirl-x.com)
3. Click URL inspection
4. Enter the URL in the textbox
5. You ll see URL inspection results. Click Request Indexing.

[image]

[image]